# Exception in Ehcache when trying to remove all the caches

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, ehcache, ehcache-3

I already searched for the solution as other question has also posted `java.lang.NullPointerExcpetion`.But i am not able to find my problem.I am using Ehcache 3 and I have instantiated a cache which is putting the data into the cache.

The class which is working as Cache is:

```
import org.ehcache.Cache;
import org.ehcache.CacheManager;
import org.ehcache.PersistentCacheManager;
import org.ehcache.config.ResourceType;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheConfigurationBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.CacheManagerBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.builders.ResourcePoolsBuilder;
import org.ehcache.config.units.EntryUnit;
import org.ehcache.config.units.MemoryUnit;
import org.ehcache.expiry.Duration;
import org.ehcache.expiry.Expirations;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class CacheHelper {

    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    private Cache<String,GenericClassForMap> mapPerson;


    private static Timer timer;

    public CacheHelper() {
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new Helper();

        timer.schedule(task, 2, 5000);

    }

    //initialziing cache
    public void putInCacheFromDb() {
        System.getProperties().setProperty("java -Dnet.sf.ehcache.use.classic.lru", "true");
        cacheManager= CacheManagerBuilder
                .newCacheManagerBuilder().build();
        cacheManager.init();

        //for map
        mapPerson = cacheManager
                .createCache("cacheOfmap", CacheConfigurationBuilder
                        .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                                String.class,GenericClassForMap.class,
                                ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(100000)).withExpiry(Expirations.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.of(60000,
                                TimeUnit.SECONDS))));
        Map<Integer,Person> mp=new HashMap<>();
        mp.put(1,new Person(1,"om"));

        mapPerson.put(CACHE_MAP_PARAMETER,new GenericClassForMap(mp));

    }

    //method to clear the cache
    public void clearAllCache(){
        System.out.println("cache is being cleared........");
          cacheManager.close();
      }

}
```

The data is being inserted in the cache when i run the program and is printed as:

```
 coming from map
[Person{id=1, name='om'}]
```

I am putting the timer for cache and in 15second the cache needs to be refreshed.So,I tried using the Helper.java class as,

```
import com.cache.cachemanager.CacheHelper;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Helper extends TimerTask
{
    public static int i = 0;

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Timer ran " + ++i);

        if(i==15){
            try {

                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("system is sleeping");
                CacheHelper cacheHelper=new CacheHelper();
                cacheHelper.clearAllCache();
               cacheHelper.putInCacheFromDb();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception at:

```
system is sleeping
 cache is being cleared........
Exception in thread "Timer-6" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.cache.cachemanager.CacheHelper.clearAllCache(CacheHelper.java:309)
  at com.cache.timer.Helper.run(Helper.java:25)
```

I tried to debug the program and I am seeing the null pointer exception is coming from :

```
 cacheManager.close();
```

My cacheManager is being null.But When I try to clear the cache from API request,it is able to clear the cache.I am not using spring framework.Why is my `cacheManager` being null but it is being removed easily when called through API Like:

http://localhost:8080/myresource/clearCache ,my cache is being cleared easily.

```
cache is being cleared........
11:19:31,154 INFO  [org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager] (default task-8) Cache 'cacheOfmap' removed from EhcacheManager.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling your `clearAllCache` method, you created a `new CacheHelper()`. Thus, the `cacheManager` attribute of this instance is never initialized (you intiliaze it only in the `putInCacheFromDb` method).
I guess when you call it through API, you have a bean/singleton instance that was called to fill your cache and is then never destroyed. So this instance must be used.

**EDIT** : To answer the question Why initialize `cacheManager` in the constructor.
Your current code runs as following :

```java
    // CacheHelper constructor is called to initialize a new CacheHelper
    // => cacheManager attribute is not initialized
    CacheHelper cacheHelper = new CacheHelper();
    // This method will call cacheManager.close().
    // => cacheManager is currently null => NullPointerException
    cacheHelper.clearAllCache();
    // This method will initialize the cacheManager attribute
    // => Too late the Exception already occured
    // => So, need to initialize cacheManager attribute before calling clearAllCache()
    // => the constructor is the best place to do this here.
    cacheHelper.putInCacheFromDb();
```

Comment: i tried even using inject method,it showed me the null pointer .. i tried also @Inject
 private CacheHelper cacheHelper;

Comment: Initialize ```cacheManager``` in the constructor of ```CacheHelper``` instead of ```putInCacheFromDb```. It is useless to delay this initialization

Comment: you just save my day.but can u tell me the reason why i needed to put inside the constructor

Comment: the null pointer exception has gone but cache is not being cleared as only "cache is being cleared........" message is printed

Comment: The message like Cache 'cacheOfmap' removed from EhcacheManager. is not shwoing